# log4net and ints

Tags: logging, log4net

I have been working a bit with log4net and have been inserting extra fields, but I have problems with adding int fields. Could anyone show a configuration where an int is used, since I have not been able to find it on their [homepage](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html).

I normally just use a configuration like:

```
 <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@orderid" />
        <dbType value="string" />
        <size value="64" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" />
    </parameter>
```

But it would be more optimal for searching in the log database if this field could have been an int instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [dbType property](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter.DbType.html) is of type [System.Data.DbType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dbtype(VS.71).aspx). There, you can use the Int32 value to represent integers.

Comment: What about Char? Thanks! It's not listed there. Thanks!

Comment: @Euridice01 that would be the non-unicode character strings, use either `AnsiString` or `AnsiStringFixedLength`.

Answer (score 26):

Just changing it to Int32 did not fix the issue for me. For others looking to solve this problem, here's the solution:

```
        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@UserID" />
            <dbType value="Int32" />
            <size value="32" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
                <key value="UserID" />
            </layout>
        </parameter>
```

This will also deal with NULLs

Comment: Thank you!! For future readers, this will pickup values set in the log4net.GlobalContext as well. In the above example (this answer), if you set the GlobalContext "UserID" (where UserID is the key), and you set the value, this code will pickup the value.  and YES!! nulls are handled.  Thank you!